# IOS fcm push notification не работает

Tags: ios, firebase, phonegap, cordova, fcm

Создал простое приложение phonegap 7.0.1 и phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0. Скачал с console.firebase.com файлы конфигураций для иос и андроид. На андроид нотификации приходят отлично и с консоли фаербейс и через постман к примеру. На ИОС ничего не приходит, хотя ответ сервера сигнализирует об успешной отправке. Напишите в коментарии если нужен код с какие то файлов или пример запроса

Код клиента

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
// 'pause', 'resume', etc.
onDeviceReady: function () {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {},
        browser: {
            pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
        },
        ios: {
            alert: "true",
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
    });
    console.log('deviceReady');
    push.on('registration', (data) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        fetch('http://nazarkalytiuk.azurewebsites.net/regid', {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },                
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(c => c.json().then(s => console.log(s)))

        fetch('http://192.168.2.100:1337/regid', {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },                
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(c => c.json().then(s => console.log(s)))
    });
},

// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function (id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

app.initialize();
```

В корне проекта лежать файлы plist и json с firebase.

Comment: Покажите ваш код клиента